# How do I add accented characters to PDF info without using hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, accents, characters

Using pdflatex, I'm looking to add PDF information into by document, including an accented name (Rónán Daly). Normally I'd use hyperref to do this; however, the conference I'm submitting to is complaining about generated links and bookmarks - I can stop the generation of bookmarks, but not links. So I'm looking at the option of using `\pdfinfo`, with `/Author`, `/Title` and `/Keyword`. However, I can't seem to add the accented characters correctly. I'm currently using ASCII, but could change this if necessary. Any ideas on how to solve either of these problems?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How are you inputting the accented letters? You can edit your question to show it; particularly important is what input encoding you're using.

Comment: Ulrike's solution is probably the best one for your problem, but I just wanted to point out that hyperref has the option `hidelinks`: "Hide links (removing color and border)". The links are still "clickable" but you no longer see the links (link-border or link colour). Once I had the same issue with an editor, who was satisfied with hidden links.

Comment: Normally this would the solution I would use, but I should point out that this was not an option in my case, as the pdf was being scanned automatically to find links and bookmarks and was hence being rejected by the submission system; with hidelinks, the links are invisible, but still present.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfinfo{%
/Author(R\string\363n\string\341n Daly)/Title(blub)/Subject()}

\begin{document}
abc 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works perfectly!

Comment: In addition to Ulrike's answer, you can find a table of 3-digit codes to be used after `\string` here: http://www.pjb.com.au/comp/diacritics.html, under the column header `Octal`.